# Cannot use import statement outside a module error after export ZIP from CodeSandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, phaser-framework, matter.js

I've downloaded this Phaser/MatterJS [example from Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j44k3844j3) (->File ->Export to ZIP).
Running it locally returns this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - index.js:1

How to fix this?

What I tried so far:

- I've installed all dependencies
- Updated to latest NodeJS
- Running it with a local server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you have seen yourself the javascript that is written in the files is not something that the browsers understand out of the box, and so errors were thrown your way.

To send js that browsers understand, you need to use a tool like webpack, parcel. already in the project you shared parcel is used.

You have to do the following:

- install the dependecies of the probject
- in the root dir of the project run `npm run start`
- parcel will bundle the files and then open an html page with the results

unfortunately when i tried this parcel did not work for me, there were errors related to JSON loading, however i have managed to get the game to work, by running `npm run build`, this will output for you the build files in a folder called dist.

Go to the dist folder, and start a local server there and visit the file it should work, however again for me it did not work. but i noticed that its due to parcel not getting the correct relative path of the bundled js file.

To solve that, open the index.html file in the dist folder, you will find that there is one script there

```
<script src="/js.d8530414.js"></script>
```

I had to change that to

```
<script src="./js.d8530414.js"></script> // because this was the correct file in my file system
```

After that visit the html file in the dist folder, and the game works fine.

Obviously this way of working is not conveninent, since for each change you want to see you have to build the project again using `npm run build`. You need to solve the problem of `npm run start` not working, it could be that this problem never occurs to you if you are on different os than mine. If it happens then i suggest updating parcel and trying again, if problem still persists, then you can [look here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/501) since issue seems related to phaser wanting the json file as json, while parcel compiling it to javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<script type = "module" src = "./js/index.js">
```

You have to tell the browser that this js file is a module, then it will change some things on the backside for you to use this. [This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/) is very helpful for getting started with modules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "phaser". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: That looks like your path from index.js to the phaser module has a problem, have you check that?